# How to search string in all files firefox developer 56

Tags: firefox-developer-edition

I can't find a way to search a string in all .js and .css files on Firefox Developer Edition 56.0b4.

I found a way, but it was before versions 52. I wonder why they removed this feature?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While not listed on [MDN Dev Tools Search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Search) page, Firefox Developer (Quantum) 58 once again includes the ability to search ALL files. I was missing this and almost defected to Chrome, but the tool set is way less intuitive.

From the debugger panel  Mac the key shortcut is CMD-SHIFT-F.

[image: Firefox Developer edition v58 Debugger panel]

Comment: As far as I can see with Ctrl-Shift-F (on Windows) in the Debugger one can only search within js files. Do you know how to search within css files, too? I tred Ctrl-Shift-F in the Style Editor but it opens up a replace function.

Comment: Is there a way to search through all CSS files in the style editor?

Answer (score 1):

The new debugger front end, aka [debugger.html](https://github.com/devtools-html/debugger.html), did not have this feature until relatively recently.

For Firefox 56, if you really need this feature, you can try going back to the old debugger.  The old debugger is not as nice in many ways; but it does have this feature.  The old debugger can be selected via a pref in `about:config`.

I believe project search is available in the new debugger front end in Firefox 57.

Comment: It's a shame they removed such a time-saving feature on version 56; it's also fortunate that they came back to their senses on version 57.

Comment: I think it wasn't a question of removing it -- it just wasn't considered a blocker for the first release of the new front end.  But yes, it turned out to be highly desired so I think it was bumped up in priority a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The preference to go back to the old debugger is `devtools.debugger.new-debugger-frontend`